# How use multiple bundle ID's with iOS Storekit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

My project has the following bundle id's(all fixed by configuration):

- es.myproject.dev
- es.myproject.pre
- es.myproject.prod

But only `es.myproject.prod` is returning the list of subscriptions from AppStore. The others bundleID's has not subscriptions in AppStore because they are only used for testing environment purposes.

Is there a way to tell Store kit use an specific String as a Bundle ID? So no matter the current bundle ID, I can always ask for subscriptions of `es.myproject.prod` to the AppStore.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: Have you also added apps for all those Bundle IDs in App Store Connect? You'll need 3-apps there with the same products configured

Comment: I don't think so. For me, it worked to create separate apps for the different bundle IDs. A bundle id is a unique id for a specific app.